# Magnet and magnetometer under acceleration

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Say I have a magnet and a magnetometer glued at opposite ends of a fully inert, infinitely rigid, finite length stick.

Will the magnetometer measurement stay constant if the stick is accelerated or rotated?

Comment: My hunch based on zero math and less experience with relativistic EM necessary to answer this question is that the answer is no. The field lines will bunch up along the direction of travel and the b field reading will change. If so then such a device could be used as an accelerometer.